# Ng-click changing key,value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
{{ctrlTest}}<hr/>
<div ng-repeat="elements in filter">
    <div>
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filter.producers" ng-show="value">
            {{key}}<a ng-click="filter.producers.key=false"> X</a>
        </li>
    </div>
    {{filter.producers}}
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlTest = "Filters";
        $scope.filter = {"producers":   {"Ford":true,"Honda":true,"Ferrari":true}}
});
```

I am trying to make a ng-click that would set each label to false when clicking in a link, but I haven't achieved to do it properly as the key values are not fixed (they should be treated as variables).

So far I have tried it his way.

http://jsfiddle.net/Joe82/wjz8270z/5/

Thanks in advance!

Ps: I cannot change the json structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to access the element of object by its key, to ensure that there references would not get lost & binding will work

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filter.producers" ng-show="value">
   {{key}}<a ng-click="filter.producers[key]=false"> X</a>
</li>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjz8270z/7/)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Joe82 Glad to know that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You also call a function and set value **false**

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filter.producers" ng-show="value">{{key}} {{value}}<a ng-click="setValue(key)"> X</a>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.setValue = function(key){
    $scope.filter.producers[key.toString()] = false;
}
```

see this link http://jsfiddle.net/wjz8270z/8/

Comment: Thanks, I keep the other one as the correct answer as it was more straighforward, but this one is valid as well.